# Activating a function if a div is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently writing a full screen slider with animated elements on the inside. I want these interior elements to be activated by the same button as the slider (right direction key) and therefore need to firstly check if they are there, and secondly activate them one by one. I have an idea of how to go about this, in a similar way that the sections were counted and named in the example, however as somewhat of a newbie at jQuery/Javascript I feel at a bit of a loss. The logic I am trying to apply is basically:

```
Onleftclick {

Check if there are any "unactivated" elements in the slide

If there isn't any, move on

If there are elements in the slide, activate a function (eg "anim1) and change the "unactivated" div to "activated"

As the animation is activated, the elements class changes to "activated"

}
```

This is my first attempt at creating something from scratch without tutorials and I'd appreciate someone better versed in javascript shining some light on my issue. At the moment I am trying to make it so if there is an "unactive" div inside this it gets changed to "unactive" and the check is run again.

A codepen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYbVxG

The current file hosted online:
http://johncashin.net/test_sites/marc_comic_2/

The statement in question:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //This counts the length of the sections
      //var page is a variable that counts how many panels have been put across
      var page = 0;
      var sectionCount = $("section").length;
      //This sets the variable bodysize, which multiplies viewportwidth by sectioncount
      $('.container').css({
        'width': (vpw * sectionCount) + 'px'
      });
      // Programatically add the class "1","2","3" etc to the sections consecutively, so     they can be scrolled to (ie scrollTo:3)
  $('section').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('s' + i);
  });
  // This is the keypress to activate scroll function 
  // there is also a variable that will stop it going above the amount of sections in the page.
  window.onkeyup = function(scrollkey) {
    var key = scrollkey.keyCode ? scrollkey.keyCode : scrollkey.which;
    if (key == 39) {
      if (page < sectionCount - 1) {
        page++;
        TweenLite.to(window, 1, {
          scrollTo: {
            x: $(".s" + page).position().left
          },
          ease: Power2.easeIn
        });
      } else {}
    } else if (key == 37) {
      //This adds backwards scrolling functionality, and stops the page variable from going any lower than 0, 
      if (page > 0) {
        page--;
        TweenLite.to(window, 1, {
          scrollTo: {
            x: $(".s" + page).position().left
          },
          ease: Power2.easeIn
        });
      } else {}
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add your (relevant) "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" code to your question, should those other sites fall over, fail, delete old content or reorganise, this question becomes nonsensical and useless without the context. (Also, and this is intended merely as advice, there is a specific reason (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#help-post-body, specifically number **1**, to close questions that don't include the relevant code).

Comment: The script I am using has now been added.

Comment: Delegate the event to document and use the css selector for the elements that need to respond to the event.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie here so I don't quite get what you mean by this, as in some kind of event that would be triggered when the object is on screen?

Comment: Fire custom events on the keypress like $.event.trigger("myleft") or $.event.trigger("myright").  Have the elements in the slider observe the events through delegation.  $(document).on({"myleft" : function() {foo}}, {"myright" : function() {bar}}, "selector for elements")  This way each element in the slider can be made aware the event happened and control their own behavior

Comment: Here's a fiddle for multiple subscribers to custom event.  Your section elements can subscribe and handle themselves.  Your code will magically simplify itself.  http://jsfiddle.net/ccav/1zag2nd8/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will check for any occurrence of a div having the class `unactive` and will call a function `anim1()` and remove the class and add a new class `active`:

```
$("div.unactive").on('click', function () {
    anim1();
    var obj = $("div.unactive");
    obj.removeClass("unactive");
    obj.addClass("active");
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uasthp0/2/

Comment: Awesome thanks I'll work on adding that to my script.

Comment: @MarcMurray Your welcome if you feel this answered your question please accept it as an answer so others know this issue is resolved.  Thanks and happy coding! :)

Comment: Having an issue with using this code as a precursor to the IF statement posted above, I would want this code to run only inside of each section, would I have to do a different statement for each section?